# Where should I post a question regarding speaker wattage and amps?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question regarding speaker wattage and amps, but I don't know which community to post it on. Super user seems to be more about software and/or directly relating to computers, and amature radio seems to be specifically about wireless broadcasting of sound.

Comment: Maybe [this one](http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: posted on Hardware Recommendations http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/1682/what-amp-can-i-use-for-these-speakers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you consider yourself a professional in the field, you could try [Sound Design](https://sound.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), there are some questions about speakers there too.

If the question is more technical, and specified on 'how does it work', [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) might be an option.

If you want to buy something, [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is an option.

Comment: Thanks for the very specific response! Definitely not a professional and i'm not all that interested in how it works, so i suppose i'm really just looking for what i can use to make it work. Hardware Recommendations it is!

Comment: Okay. Make sure to check their meta and help center it your specific question is on-topic there. Good luck!